# Gradient Colors OnMouseOver (disabling the style color)???

Tags: javascript, html, css, gradient, onmouseover

So I have created a table and I've tried to add onmouseover effect for it, so I can change the background color for the cells. Obviously, when there is no set color for the background (in the style) everything works like a charm. But when there it, I can't figure it our... Any help?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
 </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = true;
</script>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .tableX td
    {
        width: 33.33%;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: 'Sans Serif',segoe UI light, Century Gothic;
        color: #FFFFFF;

    }
        .tableX td.largeLightBlue
        {
            height: 150px;
            -moz-border-radius: 7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            width: 33.33%;
            font-size: 18px;
            background: linear-gradient(#1ba3c7, #13738C);
            text-align: left;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI','Century Gothic', sans-serif;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            padding-left: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .tableX td.largeGreen
        {
            height: 150px;
            -moz-border-radius: 7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            width: 33.33%;
            font-size: 18px;
            background: linear-gradient(#35a44f, #297E3D);
            text-align: left;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI','Century Gothic', sans-serif;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            padding-left: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .tableX td.largeBlue
        {
            height: 150px;
            -moz-border-radius: 7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            width: 33.33%;
            font-size: 18px;
            background: linear-gradient(#0C63CD, #07366F);
            text-align: left;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI','Century Gothic', sans-serif;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            padding-left: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    .tableX
    {
        width: 740px;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 10px;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableX">
    <tr>
        <td onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#E01B6A';" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor='#FAD957';" onclick="if (link) window.location ='http://www.yahoo.com'" class="largeLightBlue"  >
            <b>Some sample text</b><br />
            <ul>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet one</li>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet two</li>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet three</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td onclick="if (link) window.location ='http://www.google.com'" class="largeGreen">
            <b>Second Sample text</b>
            <ul>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet one</li>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet two</li>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet three</li>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet four</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td onclick="if (link) window.location ='http://www.bing.com'" class="largeBlue" >
            <b>Third Sample Box</b>
            <ul>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet one</li>
                <li style="font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: text-top;">Bullet two</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You apply a background-gradient through the CSS, and on mouseover you replace it with a solid color. On mouseout you replace again with another solid color. What did you want to happen ?

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli  To be honest I do not consider myself a professional and I am quite confused.Do you have a suggestion? Or an advice for a newbie? P.S. I never said the code was flawless, but sadly, I am just a human being :)

Comment: it was not an accusation ... it is just not clear what you want to happen.. can you describe the functionality you *want* ?

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding really :) Basically, what I was trying to achieve is: onmouseover, I would like the background color set in CSS style to be ignored, and instead of it- used the color, set with : onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#E01B6A';"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onmouseover` you are targeting only a `background-color`, not `background` property, which you are using in your CSS. Setting `style.background` instead of `style.backgroundColor` fixes the issue. [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JWv63/)

Comment: I do feel like an idiot right now... Thank you very much! I am guessing attention to little details is what I'm truly missing :)